# Password Cracking

Tags: python, passwords

I've asked this question once before on here and didn't get the answer I was looking for, but I got another method of doing it. so here I go again.

(The problem with the previous found answer was that it was extremely efficient, a bit too efficient. I couldn't count comparisons, and I wanted it to be the most bare bone way of finding the password, so that I can implement a rating system to it.)

I am looking to make a password rating program that rates a password based off of the length of time, and the amount of comparisons the program had to make in order to find the correct password.

I'm looking to use multiple different methods in order to crack the input, ex : comparing the input to a database of common words, and generating all possibilities for a password starting with the first character.

**Problem :**

I can't find a way to start with one element in a list, we will call it `A`.

Running `A` through `chr(32) - chr(127)` (`'space'` - `'~'`), and then adding a second element to a list called `B`.

For the second loop, set `A = chr(32)` and `B` would then run through `chr(32) - chr(127)`. `A` would then turn into `chr(33)` and `B` would run through all characters and so forth. until all possible options have been compared, then for the next loop it would add another element onto the list and continue the search, starting with `chr(32)`, `chr(32)`, `chr(32-127)`.  Continuing this pattern until it finds the correct password.

This is the closest I could get to something that would work (I know it's terrible).

```
while ''.join(passCheck) != ''.join(usrPassword) :


    for i in range(0, len(usrPassword)) :
        if ''.join(passCheck) != ''.join(usrPassword) :
            passCheck.append(' ')

            for j in range(32, 127) :
                if ''.join(passCheck) != ''.join(usrPassword) :
                    passCheck[i] = chr(j)
                    for k in range(0, len(passCheck)) :
                        for l in range(32, 127) :
                            if ''.join(passCheck) != ''.join(usrPassword) :
                                passCheck[k] = chr(l)
                                print(passCheck)
```

Comment: It's not clear for me what you want to accomplish here. If this is a real use case then a better way of checking the strength of the password is to check against a set of requirements, like: password length; if password contains big and small letters, numbers and special characters. You can also test against a dictionary of known passwords.

If you want to generate all possible permutations of a string then checkout `itertools.permutations`, it will do it for you.

Comment: you don't have to check password. In this method of rating longer password will have bigger rate and `B` will have bigger rate then `A` and `ABC` will have "rate" `(ord(A)-32)*95*95 + (ord(B)-32)*95 + (ord(C)-32)` - so you don't need all this `for`-loop - except one loop which iterate chars in password.

Comment: @marke In my explanation, I say that I am trying to make the most bare bone version that I can, using the least amount of libraries, and then slowly work my way up to making a more efficient version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is that you probably want to ask a different one, unfortunately.

Checking password strength is *not* as simple as calculating all possible combinations, Shannon entropy, etc.

What matters is what's called "guessing entropy", which is a devilishly complex mix of raw bruteforce entropy, known password lists and password leak lists, rules applied to those lists, Levenshtein distance from the elements in those lists, human-generated strings and phrases, keyboard walks, etc.

Further, password strength is *deeply* rooted in the question "How was this password generated?" ... which is very hard indeed to automatically detect and calculate *after the fact*. As humans, we can *approximate* this in many cases by reverse-engineering the *psychology* of how people select passwords ... but this is still an art, not a science.

For example, 'itsmypartyandillcryifiwantto' is a terrible password, even though its Shannon entropy is quite large. And 'WYuNLDcp0yhsZXvstXko' is a randomly-generated password ... but now that it's public, it's a bad one. And until you know how passwords like 'qscwdvefbrgn' or '[ji32k7au4a83](https://gizmodo.com/why-ji32k7au4a83-is-a-remarkably-common-password-1833045282)' were generated, they look strong ... but they are *definitely* not.

So if you apply the strict answer to your question, you're likely to get a tool that dramatically overestimates the strength of many passwords. If your goal is to actually encourage your users to create passwords resistant to bruteforce, you should instead encourage them to use randomly generated passphrases, and ensure that your passwords are stored using a very slow hash (Argon2 family, scrypt, bcrypt, etc. - but be sure to bench these for UX and server performance before choosing one).

References and further reading (disclaimer: some are my answers or have my comments):

- https://security.stackexchange.com/a/4631/6203
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4630/how-can-we-accurately-measure-a-password-entropy-range
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/127434/what-are-possible-methods-for-calculating-password-entropy
- https://security.stackexchange.com/a/174555/6203

Comment: Thanks for all of this information, I will be looking into it in the days to come. I find this to be a correct answer, not because it gave the answer I was looking for, but changed my outlook on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you check in alphabetic order then you need only one loop to calculate it how many times it would have to check it

You have 96 chars (127-32+1)

```
password = 'ABC'

rate = 0

for char in password:
    rate = rate*96 + (ord(char)-31)

print(rate)
```

Comment: This works well, but how would I be able to find the time it would take to crack the correct password?

Comment: calculate how long you take to check one char and then you have `rate * time_for_one_char`

Comment: frankly, if you check in alphabetic order then `~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~` would need the longest time.